# Why do scripting languages use an interpreter?

Tags: scripting

I know that scripting languages don't use a compiler but rather are interpreted. But I can't find information why exactly is it beneficial? What do they gain by being interpreted?

Comment: You are assuming too much. This was true, say, 20 – 30 years ago. Today, for example, JavaScript is a widely compiled — just-in-time at least.

Answer (score 0):

the positives -

- easier to create as they piggyback on an existing code system (c/cpp)
- syntax easier to work with in most cases as the creators can focus on that rather than writing a compiler.

drawbacks:

- need to provide the runtime package to use the code as it's not compiled down to native machine code.  (it's instead interpreted into c functions,  need the runtime to referee this)
- not quote as fast as running native machine code

Answer (score 0):

Scripting languages are designed to be interpreted. They are executed sequentially and the source itself is executed. Compare to something like C++ where a compile and link phase are fundamental to the language itself, and by the time you execute it, the source code is long gone.

So the default position is to interpret scripting languages. Interpreters may even compile in the background for optimization purposes.

So what are the advantages of interpretation versus compilation?

- Simpler development environment. No compile process *vastly* simplifies development. Scripting languages don't require the effort of establishing a whole development environment.
- Scripting languages can be used in small chunks - for example inline script in a webpage, or a little event handler in an application plugin. C code for example does not stand alone in small chunks like this.

Comment: How does this answer the question "why"?

Comment: Your first sentence is basically an answer like "Why do cars have four wheels? Because they are designed with four wheels". I would think the OP is asking for an explanation of the connection between the act of "scripting" and the act of "interpreting".